# Problems with the eigenvalues calculated using NDEigenvalue

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I'm trying to solve a Sturm-Liouville problem like

$\qquad -\psi''(z)+(\frac{1}{z}+2\,z)\psi'(z)=\lambda\,\psi(z)$

using `NDEigensystem` in order to learn how to use this tool. The spectrum should be `{4, 8, 12, 16, 20, ...}`.

I tried this code for the equation above:

```
{mass,states} = 
   NDEigensystem[
     {-psi''[z]+(1/z + 2 z)psi[z], DirichletCondition[psi[z] == 0, True]}, psi[z], {z, 0, 20}, 8,
      Method -> 
        {"SpatialDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement",
         "MeshOptions"->{"MaxCellMeasure"->0.0001}}}]
```

where `Eqn` is just the differential (Liouville) operator that I defined above. I also impose Dirichlet conditions for $\psi(z)$ at $z\to 0$.

But I getting some problems with this code.

First, the eigenvalues change (a lot) when I change the interval. For example, with [0, 10] I get `{4, 8, 12, 16, 20.001, 27.3062-2.30156 I}`. When I change the interval to `[0, 20]`, I get `{4., 8., 12., 15.8473, 17.0221-1.78342I, 17.0221+1.78342I, 17.6018-4.75387I, 17.6018+4.75387I}`.

Second, (as you can see above), the eigenvalues appear with non-zero imaginary part. This problem has real eigenvalues, so I don't understand what it is happening.

I have read the information about `NDEigenvalues`, but I still do not understand why I'm getting these problems. So if anyone could give me some advice I would be thankful.

Comment: Can you show your code for the psi[z] ? And what output do you get when you run the code you provided so far?

Comment: Yeah, sure! Let me re-write the question!

Comment: sweet! Let me know when you post the function definitions and I’ll take a look, there could be something in your syntax, and I am just generically a curious scientist :) but also I can’t help you properly without it

Comment: Mmm, when you say function definitions, are you thinking on how I define the boundary conditions or something related? If that's so, then I used Dirichlet conditions at the origin and it is supposed that the function is real-valued.

Comment: @Mike How did you get spectrum {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, ...}?

Comment: @Mike yes, how do you define your code for your psi[z] function? I realize now I should be asking for your Eqn definition, can you provide this code? You have listed it nicely in TeXForm, which looks quite nice visually, but not in a mathematica input I, or any one could use to test the code you've provided so far. Specifically, you'd be defining something like: "psi[z_]:=" or similar. What are these pieces of code?

Comment: What is your boundary condition on the right, that solutions decay?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I just solve the Eigenvalue differential equation using DSolve. The form of the spectrum appears from the solutions. This equation in particular is analytical and I'm using it as a toy model to understand how NDEigensystem works.

Comment: @KraZug I'm supposing that the solutions are square integrable, so they are decaying at infinity.

Comment: @CATrevillian Actually I didn't use any specific definition for the function psi[z].  I just put the Liouville operator inside the NDEigensystem, according to the Wolfram site that I consulted. I just put explicitly the differential operator in the code that I show you above, in the question.

Comment: I believe you are trying to solve a problem on the half line. But instead, you ask Mathematica to solve a Dirichlet problem on a finite interval. Note that it seems to me that your code imposes a Dirichlet condition at both ends. As you change the interval, you change the problem and get different results, as one should expect (the whole line eigenfunctions have no reason to all vanish at x=10 or x=20...)

Comment: Yes, I think @FrancoisVigneron is the reason here. For the eigenvalues closer to 0, the domain truncation doesn't affect it much.

Comment: @FrancoisVigneron, if I remove the Dirichlet condition, I have the same issue: the spectrum depends on the interval.  In order to do a different approach, I transform the equation into a hyperbolic one (Schrödinger like) and I found an associated potential function just to see if there's any bounded states. In this case, I found the expected Eigenvalues with the Dirichlet condition and the NDEigenvalue procedure, and they do not change with the interval. I honestly do not know why it works now...